# Is unix.stackexchange.com a proper place to ask questions about elementaryOS?

Tags: support, questions

I use a different (although Ubuntu-based) types of Linux and I like, elementaryOS.  But there are not a lot of questions on that on Stack Exchange.

Is U&L the proper place for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the U&L [about page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/about):

> Unix & Linux Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of Linux, FreeBSD and **other Un*x-like operating systems**

(emphasis mine)

It would appear to be on topic on that site.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. Any questions related to Un*x like operating systems are welcome here. We even already have the 2 tags [elementary-os](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-os) and [elementary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary) which a couple of questions each under them.

Given Elementary's lineage it should be relatively easy for most people on U&L to either answer your questions outright or at least provide you guidance as to how to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use your best judgement. Is the problem based on other *nix utilities or something that users of other *nix systems may face? In that case you should post it on U&L.

However, if your question is extremely specific and is caused by issues in the underlying Ubuntu system, it would be a better idea to post on AskUbuntu. This is a very thin line and the best way is to use your judgement as to what fits where.

Comment: askubuntu does not encourage questions on OSes based on ubuntu but outside [the Ubuntu officially supported derivatives](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives) - also [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/684/47206) and [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5877/47206). so, U&L remains the main option

Comment: Oh. I wasn't aware of these. Although after reading the answers on the links provided, I understand why they may not want to entertain such questions. In such a case, please go ahead! U&L welcomes everyone!